# Changing MediaWiki form target urls

Tags: mediawiki

I've already successfully changed most of the `<a>` urls to prettier ones (hiding all the millions of `/w/index.php?title=foo&....` links into `/wiki/Foo?...`) through a combination of [$wgActionPaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844653/mediawiki-removing-index-php-from-url-for-other-links) and client side javascript:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('[href*="title="]').attr('href', function (i, value) {
    return value.replace(/\/w\/index.php\?title=(.+?)\&(.+?)/, "/wiki/$1?$2")
  })
})
```

(I was too lazy to translate that into PHP)

The only links left are the target urls of

- the search form
- the history page 'compare selected versions' and 'browse history' forms

How would I make these target nicer cleaner URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following `.htaccess` rule can be used to redirect *all* `/w/index.php?...&title=Article&...` links to the `/wiki/Article?...` variant:

```
# force any /w/index.php urls back to the /wiki/ variant
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} title=([^&]+) 
RewriteRule ^/?w/index.php$ /wiki/%1 [QSA,NE,R=302]
```

unfortunately the myriad forms used at various points cause the query parameters to be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in such a way that the `.htaccess` `QSA` flag fails and you end up at `/wiki/Special%3ARecentChanges` for example. This especially fails on subpages where the `%2F`'s that get inserted cause everything to break.

**EDIT:** the above percent-encoding problem can be fixed by enabling the following [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) in the server settings (doesn't work in `.htaccess` itself):

```
RewriteMap unescape int:unescape
```

and then replacing the `%1` in the `RewriteRule` line with

```
RewriteRule ^/?w/index.php$ /wiki/${unescape:%1} [QSA,NE,R=302]
```

**EDIT:** and to further remove the remaining/repeated `title=` parameter from the final url, include the following rules (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857280)):

```
# remove title query parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?title=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/?wiki/.+)$ /$1?%1&%2 [NE,R]
```

Comment: some combination of these rules breaks the `Special:UserLogin` page when it has the query `?&returnto=...`. all that happens on form submit is the login page is reloaded. removing the query before filling in the form works fine

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the following `LocalSettings.php`

```
$actions = [ 'watch', 'unwatch', 'delete', 'revert', 'rollback', 'protect', 
                'unprotect', 'markpatrolled', 'render', 'submit', 'purge' ];
foreach ($actions as $action)
        $wgActionPaths[$action] = "/wiki/$1?action=$action";
```

which change the some of the html links

and `MediaWiki:Common.js`

```
  $('#searchform').attr('action', '/wiki/Special:Search')
  $('form').attr('action', function (i, value) {
    return value.replace("/w/index.php", "/wiki/" + $('[name="title"]', this).attr('value'))
  })
  $("[name='title']",$('form')).remove()
```

to fix the search action, and the special pages forms