# Apache rewrite query param to path (url)

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have an application that had a page like `my-site.com/profile?user=<userIdHere>` and I changed the way to handle the route in order to have a clean url `my-site.com/profile/<userIdHere>`.
I would like to create a redirect from `/profile?user=101` to `/profile/101` for example.

I didn't find any example like this and I can't make it work. What I did at the moment:

```
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=(.*?)
        RewriteRule ^/profile /profile/%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

but I get a "Too many redirects" error.
Another thing I will: Sometimes I have other query parameters, like: `/profile?user=101&anotherParam=test`. How can I do to keep the other query params?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please try this - `^(.*/profile)(?:\?)(user=)(\d+)(.*)$` and you can use this as substitution text - `$1/$3$4`

Comment: Where do I have to use this? In the RewriteRule with no RewriteCond ?

Comment: RewriteCond is a condition upon which rewrite rule should be executed. If you want to change the url like you wanted then it goes inside rewrite rule.

Comment: It's not working, and debug didn't helped me.

Comment: I tried to debug the error I had with my syntax (the too many redirects error). I found that this is because it's matching, but redirecting to `/profile/101?user=101`, so it's matching another time, etc...

Comment: I think thats because you ^/profile matches the query string but u r only substituting a part of the string and the rest of the string remains. So you can try changing `^/profile.*` and substitution text `/profile/%1` and also you can change the rewritecond to use `^user=(.*)` greedy approach as you want the complete query string after user= . I believe this will most probably work.

Comment: I found a way to make it work, and posted an answer. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857280/using-htaccess-to-remove-single-query-parameter), by just removing the query param that my condition is matching (to prevent too many redirects), and I injected its value in the path:

```
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?&?user=([^&]+)&?(.*)?
        RewriteRule ^/profile$ /profile/%2?%1%3 [R=301,NC,L]
```

where %2 is `101`